# uploading a pdf using volley but gets null file on server folder

Tags: android, mysql, xml, android-studio

I am uploading a pdf file using volley library in database on hostinger domain and also in folder on same hostinger domain

Here it is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context="com.example.singhharpal.fileupload_apr26.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
    android:text="Touch the icon below to upload file to server"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ivAttachment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CHoose"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_file_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivAttachment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/b_upload"
    android:text="Upload"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="#039be5"/>
```

My java file

```
package com.example.singhharpal.fileupload_apr26;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
//import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     view.OnClickListener
{
private Button buttonClick;
private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private ImageView imageView;
File file;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 200;
String filename;
String s1,s2;
private String UPLOAD_URL ="http://harpal-projects.16mb.com/sbbs/php/file-upload2.php";
private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
private String KEY_NAME = "fname";
private String KEY_ROLL = "roll_no";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
/*
    Button textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
*/

   /*// SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userInfo",getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);       //my settings is file name

    s1=sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
    s2=sharedPreferences.getString("password","");
    t1.setText(s1);
    t2.setText(s2);*/

    //textView.setText("Welcome User " + intent.getStringExtra(RegisterStudent.KEY_USERNAME));
    buttonChoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
    //buttonClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickPic);
    buttonUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
    //imageView  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v == buttonChoose)
    {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload)
    {
        uploadImage();
    }
}

private void showFileChooser()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("image*//*;application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // special intent for Samsung file manager
    Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA_MULTIPLE");
    // if you want any file type, you can skip next line
    sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "application/pdf");
    sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    Intent chooserIntent;
    if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null)
    {
        // it is device with samsung file manager
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Open file");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { intent});
    }
    else
    {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file");
    }


    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 100);*/
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        filename=filePath.getLastPathSegment();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            file = new File(filePath.toString());
            getStringFile(file);

    }
}

public String getStringFile(File f)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

        String line ;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private void uploadImage()
{
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s)
                {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String
            String doc = getStringFile(file);

            //Getting Image Name
            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
            params.put("file", doc);
            params.put("fname", filename);



            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(){
                                     @Override
                                     public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                                         return 50000;
                                     }

                                     @Override
                                     public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                                         return 50000;
                                     }

                                     @Override
                                     public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

                                     }
                                 }
    );

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
}
```

I used php server script where i added a query to insert file into my database folder and in server folder named uploads

This is my php script

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

$file = $_POST['file'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];

$file_path = "uploads/";
$actualpath = "http://harpal-projects.16mb.com/sbbs$file_path";

 $sql = "INSERT INTO files (file,fname) VALUES ('$actualpath','$fname') ";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
             file_put_contents($file_path,base64_decode($file));

        echo "success";

 }else{
        echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

I dont know where i am getting problme as file is going into database table and also in folder in my server but it's size is 0 i.e. it is null so it is of no use ... tell me how to modify this code.??

I tried convertFileToBase64String but it gets null file too
in activtyonresult i tried this code

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        filename=filePath.getLastPathSegment();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            file = new File(filePath.toString());

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           // doc=getStringFile(file);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+doc.length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

and i used this to upload file

```
params.put("file", encodedBase64);
```

and when i used toast to see lenght of encodedBase64 it results 0 , same for 'file','fileinputreader','bytes'
  so i think it is not right or may be i am wrong..correct me

i tried this code but it gets null value....as if i didnt pick any file or the fle get lost there somewhere...

```
 public String convertFileToBase64String(File f) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    encodedFile = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedFile;
}
```

Comment: You have terrible php code. The first thing you should do is to check if your data comes in. Start with isset($_POST['file']). Do not continue if not set but echo an appropiate message.

Comment: Is 'fname' correctly received? You should tell us more.

Comment: `String getStringFile(File f)`. You cannot put an image file or a pdf file in a String.

Comment: `base64_decode($file)`. You did not sent the pdf file base64 encoded.

Comment: as of String getStringFile(File f) that i cannot put a file in string...but here im converting the file to InputStream and then using BufferedReader with that input stream i am converting the file to string to upload to the server . @greenApps
'public String getStringFile(File f)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));'

Comment: i tried
'if( isset($_POST['file']))
{ echo "File Successfully Uploaded"; }
else { echo " error uploading file"; }
then it Toasted File Succefully Uploaded when i tried to upload the file again

Comment: @greenapps this 'fname' is working......yes... in database table i have column fname and my filename and fname are same which is infact i was trying to do...so yeah this is correctly received.

Comment: Your getStringFile is nonsense. Why did you repeat it? I already saw it. And you are not base64 encoding.

Comment: So isset works. Ok. After that use `strlen($file)` to see how many bytes came in.

Comment: `String doc = getStringFile(file);` Check doc.length to see how many bytes that is.

Comment: @greenapps what do you mean by "you are  not base64 encoding" ?

Comment: Well are you? I already asked you why you have `base64_decode($file)` in your php script. For what?

Comment: And why arent you supplying those lengths i asked for?

Comment: okay @greenapps !!!!
now i understand what are you trying to say about base64 decode.
i already mentioned in my description of problem that i dont know anything about php scripting and this php script that i am using is from a free source over internet.,,,,, so i also dint know what is base64_decode is for...... i thought it is for uploading file.....

Comment: it using doc.length it gives "0" @greenapps

Comment: So now you have seen that getStringFile() is nonsense. You cannot put a pdf file in a string. What you can do however is put a pdf file base64 encoded in a string. So do that. The php script expects that. Name your function `convertFileToBase64String()`.

Comment: naming the fucntion wont do it..... you have to tell me how to convert file to Base 64 String and tell me what changes i have to make in my php script.... if you can please modify my code and post it again.... i will appreciate this very much.... @greenapps

Comment: Of course renaming will not do. You have to make that function yourself. No not yourself. Examples you can find all over this site. Just search and google for it. You dont have to change the php script. You are adapting your android code. Only error checking could be made better for that script.

Comment: @greenapps i tried that but it gives null pointer exception which means my files's size or length is 0...so help me here....

Comment: Yes you receive 0 bytes because you send 0 bytes because doc.length == 0. You should implement that base64 encoding runction and you are done. Null pointer exception? Where? Please post your code in an extra code block. So not in a comment. Which file size are you talking about? The pdf file?

Comment: yes pdf file size which is stored in folder on my hostinger server.... it shows size 0 ...and cannot be opened,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: i tried that fucntion but didnt worked.... please do me a favour.....
can you do that for me.... implementation of that fucntion.......
As you can see my code above...i am choosing a file from sdCard and then using activityforresult and sending intent data i.e. choosen file to activityfor result function... then from there please tell me how to handle that intent and upload file to server...
i am not getting how to do that...so  help me here...!! @greenapps

Comment: Just show the code you tried. And the code which makes you think that the file size is 0. With full error messages please.

Comment: @greenapps i just edited the question and added the code where im trying to convert file to base64 so please correct it... and i have already told u im dont knwo anything about php script and im also new to android

Comment: once you try the whole code you will see the error message @greenapps in my case i used toast to show the lentgth of converted file... Inputstream and bytes array..they show null or 0 when i choose a file and then trying to upload it.

Comment: You have several toasts which display namefile name or path. Please tell what you see. Also tell the value of filePath.toString() and file.getAbsolutePath(). Also add file.exists() to see if the file exists. Tell us.

Comment: `filePath.toString()` and `filePath.getPath()`. Log or toast them and tell us.

Comment: `fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);` Isnt there a return value which tells you how many bytes are actually read? Try `int nread =fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);`. What is nread?

Comment: filePath.getPath() gives the file path from my storage and i have toasted them all.... and filepath.tostring converts it to string.... and you can also try and upload a file and you can see

Comment: My god. Tell the paths that are displayed by the toasts. We do not see the toasts. Only you. So you should tell what you see. And tell the other paths i asked for.

Comment: could you please do that,,,? i am getting confused a lot...... you can run entire code ...please do me favour

Comment: TELL US WHICH PATHS ARE DISPLAYED BY THOSE TOASTS!

Comment: just wait a sec............!!

Comment: using toast in onactivity result wont display them i dont know why......
bu ti used toast for encodedbase64 in uploadFile()
and i toasted file.getLength also in uploadfile....there i saw 0 and null value
sorry...as i told i am getting nervous and confused talking to you experts sorry

Comment: Well then log them and look in the logcat and tell us.

Comment: on toasting filepath.getPath() i get 
/storage/extSdCard/filename.pdf
yes i get this toast @greenapps

Comment: Have you requested READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file?

Comment: on Toasting filePath.toString() i get
content://org.openintents.filemanager/storage/extsdcard/filename.pdf

as im using OI filemanager by Openintents

Comment: He he finally you give the wanted and long searched for information. That isnt a file system path but a content resolver path. So you cannot use the `File` class.

Comment: so tell me what and how to do :( ?

Comment: Remove the line with the file input stream and replace by `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()); (maybe the member function is named a little bit different).

Comment: then where i am using 'finputstreamreader.read(bytes)'
i should use 'is.read(bytes)' ??

Comment: Then you use is.read().

Comment: and what about 
'Uri filePath = data.getData(); //data is intent that is file i slected fromsdcard
             filename=filePath.getLastPathSegment();
            
                file = new File(filePath.toString());' ??

Comment: You throw that all away of course.

Comment: null pointer expception at '                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
'

Comment: please can you try new code and when file is uplaoding send it to me.... as  i will be now connecting to internet after one day...as im going to travel now... please help me as soon as  you can

Comment: You are using file.length. And there is no file as you cannot use the File class.

Comment: Instead in a loop write the bytes from is to a ByteArrayOutputStream. When done convert to byte[].

Comment: i think if you provide me the code by doing it... i can understand easily...as i am trying what everytime a problem occurs....guys ... i am irritated from this now ... if u can do this..it will be much appreciated.... @greenapps

Comment: You really are too lazy to look around? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893851

Comment: yes you can call me lazy.. but the one who dont know anything and by the way you are guidng very goood so it has also a effect or cause of my lazyness..... 
@greenapps check the edited question i added the fucntion to convertfiel tobase64string but nothing good happened,,,so tell me more?

Comment: As you cannot use the File class you have to use the Url class. So call your function `convertUrlToBase64String(Url url)`. And call it with `convertUrlToBase64String(data.getData()) `. You know already that you cannot use FileInputStream. I already told you what you have to use instead. Why do i have to tell it twice? I gave you that link so you could see that you dont need to know the size of the file.

Comment: i get that i dont nee dto use file class...but in that link FIle class was used...okay thats why you have to tell me twice... and secondly... i didnt get.... one thing.... that when i use 'convertUrlToBase64String(data.getData())' how to call this method from OnActivtyResult and with which arguement?

Comment: That is the call already! I told you exactly how you have to call it. Inclusive argument.  Why dont you see that?

Comment: okay i get this..... but.....stilll lot of work pending here....... i dont know.... if you knwo evverythign how to do it.,,,why dont you give me exact thing what i want..... ..,,, as now i dont know.... whta to use ...eg... before this in bytes array i was usning inputstream.read(buffer) but now as i dont use inputstream so waht do ii use...and where to use this Url url?

why are you telling me everthing in parts....why cant in one step ?

Comment: Of course you will continue to use input stream and content resolver.  But you dont seem to be able to put all parts together. Well sorry for you. I tried to help you step by step. But it is as you havnt the faintest idea about whats going on and what has to happen. That last link was onlyfor you to look at the loop. Only the loop so you would understand that you did not need the file.length.

Comment: You didnt...by the way thnks for all parts,,..but still something missing

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**In java:**

```
String encode = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**in php:**

```
$file = $_POST['file']['name'];

//$fname = $_POST['fname']['tmp_name'];

$fname = $_POST['file']['tmp_name'];

$file_path = "uploads/";
$actualpath = "http://harpal-projects.16mb.com/sbbs/$file_path/$file";

$sql = "INSERT INTO files (file,fname) VALUES ('$actualpath','$fname') ";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

    file_put_contents(base64_decode($file), $file_path);
    echo "success";
}
else{

    echo "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a pdf file in a string. What you can do however is put a pdf file base64 encoded in a string. So do that. The php script expects that. Name your function`convertFileToBase64String()`.