# Upload file from android to mysql database with Base64?

Tags: php, android, mysql, file, base64

I am creating an android mobile application in which user can upload a file to the server.

I successful to upload image to server by using the following code :

```
    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

I try to send a file by using the following code but It not working.

```
public String convertFileToBase64String(File f) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedFile = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedFile;
}
```

Here the methode to upload :

```
 private void uploadFile(){
    //Showing the progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    //Disimissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();
                    //Showing toast message of the response
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Dismissing the progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme);
                        builder.setMessage("Check your connection");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.show();

                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        //TODO

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme);
                        builder.setMessage("Authentication Failure");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.show();

                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        //TODO

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme);
                        builder.setMessage("Error in server");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.show();

                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        //TODO

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme);
                        builder.setMessage("An error in the network");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.show();

                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        //TODO

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme);
                        builder.setMessage("The server response could not be parsed");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.show();

                    }
                   else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Converting Bitmap to String

            String uploaded_file = null;
            try {
                uploaded_file = convertFileToBase64String(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Getting Image Name
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            //Adding parameters
            params.put(KEY_FILE, uploaded_file);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Method to open file :

```
public void openFile(String minmeType) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType(minmeType);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // special intent for Samsung file manager
    Intent sIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
    // if you want any file type, you can skip next line
    sIntent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", minmeType);
    sIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    Intent chooserIntent;
    if (getPackageManager().resolveActivity(sIntent, 0) != null){
        // it is device with samsung file manager
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(sIntent, "Choose File");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { intent});
    }
    else {
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File");
    }

    try {
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILE_REQUEST);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No suitable file manager has been found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

OnActivity :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == FILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();

        editTextName.setText(FileName);

    }
}
```

Comment: Declare a byte[] array with the size of that file. Open a FileInputStream and in a loop read bytes from the stream in the array. After that the same two last lines as you have now.

Comment: which size ? I want to select a file with any size.

Comment: Is like that ?
`public String getStringFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
     InputStream  inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String encodedFile = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, 0);
        return encodedFile;
    }`

Comment: Please put code in a code block in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: OK ! Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: Please rename output to baos like you had before. You are encoding that small buffer. Well that will not be enough dont you think so? You wrote the content of all those buffers to the baos. But after that you are not using baos. So make a byte array out of the baos first. Like in original code. Then encode the byte array like in original code.

Comment: `String getStringFile()`. Better rename that to `convertFileToBase64String()`.

Comment: I changed the code above.It is correct ??

Comment: Well you should be able to tell us as the proof of the pudding is in the eating. I would remove that try-catch block as you want that function to throw.

Comment: I removed it.
Should I put the full code in the post ??

Comment: You should tell if it works.

Comment: No. Its not working.

Comment: Well tell what goes wrong and what goes ok. It makes no sense to only say its not working.

Comment: Well I'm using volley to upload a file to server. I don't know if the error back to the `convertFileToBase64String()` method or another problem

Comment: when I press the upload button it displays the message in `onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError)`

Comment: Yes. And... Whats the message? Whats the error? But you could check for yourself if convertFileToBase64String functions ok. You asked for that function. I helped you and i asked if it worked. That has nothing to do with Volley.

Comment: And why did you remove your old code? You should not have done that as now nobody will understand this post.

Comment: I removed it just by mistake.
Upload image work fine. But for uploading a file Is not working. That's why I think the problem is with the `convertFileToBase64String()` function

Comment: `Whats the message? Whats the error?`.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Volley", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`. That will not tell the user the error. You have to use parameter `volleyError` to display the error.

Comment: I edited the code look at it.
Now when  I press the upload button it shows me nothing.
It means there isn't error in volley or what?

Comment: Then it is a diffent `instanceoff` then you are examining there. You should add a toast when all fail. Add a final else. And what is `error` ? Shouldnt you examine `volleyError`?

Comment: Now it shows me : `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: It's `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Well then something is null there. What does the logcat tell about it? And what do you think which pointer is null? Do you see pointers? I see two possibilities for a null pointer.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.yns.uploadfile.MainActivity.convertFileToBase64String(MainActivity.java:74)
                                                                            at com.example.yns.uploadfile.MainActivity$3.getParams(MainActivity.java:167)`

Comment: line 74 : `InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());`

line 167 : `uploaded_file = convertFileToBase64String(file);`

Comment: No. As you see that gives no answer to the question which pointer is ment. It should be something in that toast statement.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.yns.uploadfile.MainActivity.convertFileToBase64String(MainActivity.j‌​ava:74)`. Well that is strange as that is in getParams() and has nothing to do with your toast. Or is this error really in getParams? You should debug better to see where things go wrong. What is on line 74?

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }` If you have that exception in getParams() you should not continue with the code. But return null. Well if that is allowed. Or not use that param. Put log statements in it. Check if there is a catch. Debug better!

Comment: On line 74 the declaration of inputStream.
`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: I think the problem in `f.getAbsolutePath()`  No ??

Comment: So is `f`null? Check before use. You should already check before you call that function. Can you log f.getAbsolutePath() ? What is its value? And... you cannot log it if `f`== null. So check before use.

Comment: `convertFileToBase64String(file);` We cannot see what `file`is. You should post all code concerning `file`.

Comment: `String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();i`. That FileName will not bring you very far. But show us how you instantiate your `File file`.

Comment: I think you have exactly the same problems as this poster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881904/uploading-a-pdf-using-volley-but-gets-null-file-on-server-folder?noredirect=1#comment61419945_36881904

Comment: And you might benefit from this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934872/copy-image-from-filepicker-intent-to-another-directory?noredirect=1#comment61430639_36934872

Comment: OK , I will see them. Thank you @greenapps