# Copy Image from FilePicker/Intent to another Directory

Tags: android, android-intent, copy, android-bitmap

I am trying to copy Image i receive from Intent to another directory. But I am unable to get it working yet. Need Help.

My Logcat:

```
04-29 14:56:22.778 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 14:56:24.944 31620-31633/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-29 14:56:24.944 31620-31633/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f5170636740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-29 14:56:26.370 31620-31633/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f517631a550
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_HOVER_ENTER, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=322.27295, y[0]=447.5, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4168947, downTime=4168760, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_HOVER_ENTER, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=322.27295, y[0]=447.5, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4168947, downTime=4168760, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to root view being removed: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_HOVER_MOVE, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=322.27295, y[0]=447.5, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=4168947, downTime=4168760, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-29 14:56:26.381 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
04-29 14:56:27.652 31620-31633/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f517631a710
04-29 14:56:29.935 31620-31630/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7247(862KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 10MB/10MB, paused 10.778ms total 53.218ms
04-29 14:56:30.051 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest D/BuildVersion: Build version >=19
04-29 14:56:30.070 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                           --------- beginning of crash
04-29 14:56:30.071 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.krupal.sqlitetest, PID: 31620
                                                                           ** java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download/2015-09-09.jpg flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.krupal.sqlitetest/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference **
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:183)
                                                                               at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:130)
                                                                               at com.example.krupal.sqlitetest.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:160)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
04-29 14:56:32.316 31620-31620/com.example.krupal.sqlitetest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31620 SIG: 9
```

Source:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PICTURE: {
                Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                    String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageURI);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                    avatar.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    copyImageToInternalStorage(new File(getPath(selectedImageURI)));
                    Log.d("BuildVersion","Build version <19");

                } else {
                    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                    try {
                        parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedImageURI, "r");
                        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
                        if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                            fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                        }
                        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                        avatar.setImageBitmap(image);
                        Log.d("BuildVersion","Build version >=19");
                        copyImageToInternalStorage(new File(getPath(selectedImageURI)));

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            (everything else)
}
```

Copy Method:

```
    private void copyImageToInternalStorage(File sourcefile) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File folder = getExternalFilesDir("ImageDatabase");
    File file = new File(folder, "IMG_"+timeStamp+".jpg");

    if(!sourcefile.exists()){
        return;
    }
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel dest = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourcefile).getChannel();
        dest = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
        if(source != null && dest != null){
            dest.transferFrom(source,0,source.size());
        }
        if(source != null){
            source.close();
        }
        if(dest != null){
            dest.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

GetPath Method:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    //  Cursor cursor=managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

But this is giving me NullPointerException. What needs to be changed?

Comment: Yes you have a NullPointerException. Where? Which pointer is null? The logcat tells you the code line.  Check pointer before use and dont use if null. What do you mean with 'this' in `But this is giving me`?

Comment: `copyImageToInternalStorage` That is a wrong function name as you are using `getExternalFilesDir`. That's external storage as you can see in the function name.

Comment: `void copyImageToInternalStorage`. You should make that 'boolean' of course. And check the return value and display to the user what happened.

Comment: I mean this whole code is giving me that exception. Yes i am going to change method name to externalstorage.

Comment: what value should i return in boolean?

Comment: @greenapps, original doubt is that i want to store the location of the image file that i choose and store it in database. But i am not able to get real path of the image that i select. I get same nullpointerexception when i try to do so.

Comment: You schould add return statements like `return false` in all catch blocks. Only at the end you should `return true`.

Comment: Do not care for the real path. You better could store in the database data.getData().getPath() or data.getData().toString(). Try them out by logging.

Comment: If you want to copy then do not use the `File` class. Make a function `copyFromUriToExternalStorage(Uri uri)` and call with `copyFromUriToExternalStorage(data.getData());`.

Comment: No not that whole code is giving you that exception. You can see in your logcat that it is the code on `MainActivity.java:160`. So then you know which pointer is null.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working code which i Have used to copy the file after clicking an image. You have to create a directory structure for it before.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CLICK_PHOTO:
                imageUri = data.getData();
                path = Utils.getRealPathFromURI(Photos.this, imageUri);
                picturePath = path.toString();

                fileName = picturePath.substring(picturePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);


                mFile = new File(Utils.getPath(getDIR), fileName);

                try {
                    copyFile(new File(picturePath), mFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                saveBitmapToFile(mFile);

                PhotoBeans bean = new PhotoBeans();
                bean.setThumbImageUrl(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
                bean.setIsImageSelected(false);

                arrayListPhoto.add(bean);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //  This will try to load your new Image

                gvImages.invalidateViews(); // then you are refreshing views and setting the adapter again below

                gvImages.setAdapter(adapter);
                //Initialize Adapter

                break;

            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                imageUri = data.getData();
                path = Utils.getRealPathFromURI(Photos.this, imageUri);
                picturePath = path.toString();

                fileName = picturePath.substring(picturePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

                mFile = new File(Utils.getPath(getDIR), fileName);

                try {
                    copyFile(new File(picturePath), mFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                saveBitmapToFile(mFile);

                PhotoBeans beans = new PhotoBeans();
                beans.setThumbImageUrl(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
                beans.setIsImageSelected(false);

                arrayListPhoto.add(beans);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //  This will try to load your new Image

                gvImages.invalidateViews(); // then you are refreshing views and setting the adapter again below

                gvImages.setAdapter(adapter);
                //Initialize Adapter
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

CopyFile()

```
 private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    //Creates a copy of the existing file
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }
}
```

Directory Structure

```
   private void createDirectoryStructure() {
    try {
        createDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "", "YourDirecrtoryName");
        createDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "YourDirecrtoryName", "FolderInsideDirectory");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createDirectory(String filePath, String directoryName) {
    try {
        File mfile= new File(filePath, directoryName);
        if (!mfile.exists()) {
            mfile.mkdirs();
            Log.e("In error", "createDirectory");
        } else {
            Log.e("In nottt error", "createDirectory");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Utils.getPath()

```
  public static String getPath(String getDIR) {
    String path = "";
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    }
    if(getDIR.equalsIgnoreCase("images")) {
        return path + "/YourDirectoryName/YourDirectoryName Images";
    }else if(getDIR.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")){
        return path + "/YourDirectoryName/YourDirectoryName Videos";
    }else {
        return path + "/YourDirectoryName/YourDirectoryName Documents";
    }
}
```

To get the path of the image from Uri.

```
   public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Log.e("Cursor", "" + cursor);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps :)