# How to store Image location (fetching from filepicker/Intent) in Sqlite

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-intent

I am new to Android Development. I am trying to store Image file location in Sqlite database. Image is received from Intent with any file manager or gallery. I want to store its real path into the database so i can retrieve it next time for any action. I don't want to use blob/dont want to store image in the database. I am not finding any better solutions. Please help.

Comment: you can create table with text column and save path there

Comment: i have a text column to save the path there but what i am not able to get is the image location from intent.

Comment: You can save image in folder something like cache if it's possible. Or save url on the image and download it in memory every time when it needed

Comment: @Krups You can store only image path in databse Right ?

Comment: Why are you starting a new thread? I already told you how you could do this but you are not even reacting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934872/copy-image-from-filepicker-intent-to-another-directory

Answer (score 0):

You can store an image in database as bytearray or also store image URL as TEXT in sqlite dataBase

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent name=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

 name.setType("image/*.png");   // It could be any files extension that your going to search

startActivityForResult(name, requestCode);
```

And also Override onActivityResult() method

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

String path=data.getData().getPath();
//Here insert the path into database
}
```

Comment: this gives me path like `/document/primary:Download/2015-09-04.jpg` instead of `/storage/emulated/0/Download/2015-09-04.jpg`. Is it wise to make corrections in path before saving it in database. What are the options to make changes to this string path? ,  @akhil Rao

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image path and always check if the path is valid or exists.

You can use an intent to pick up the image:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And get the image path:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        /** You have to call the getData or getDataString to get the images address */
        Log.i("CCC", data.getDataString());
    }
}
```

With the path you can save it in the database.

Enjoy it!!