# Open camera and save to ImageView by android testing

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, camera

In my code, camera should take photo and save it in ImageView. It works good until saving picture to the ImageView. It displays nothing!!

There are my errors:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUESTED_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
ImageView output;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button shot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    output=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if(!hasCamera())
        shot.setEnabled(false);
}
private boolean hasCamera(){
    return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}

public void lanch_camera(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent,REQUESTED_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQUESTED_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        Bitmap pic=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        output.setImageBitmap(pic);
    }
}
}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What does `data.getData()` return in the `onActivityResult` method?

Comment: the map of all extras previously added with putExtra(), or null if none have been added.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936165/how-to-store-image-location-fetching-from-filepicker-intent-in-sqlite/36961423#36961423